# Ember: Resolve complex async promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ember.js, ember-data

I have a use case where all models relations in Ember Data are loaded async. I have a route which renders Grandparents in the example below based on whether the parent.child matches a particular model.

So far I've been able to manage to resolve the grandparent and parent model async loading but then my code becomes a massive jumble.

Are there any useful strategies for filtering out the grandparents without having to deal with promises at every level?

**Example model definitions**

```
App.Grandparent = DS.Model.extend({
    ...
    parents: DS.hasMany('Parent', { async: true })
});

App.Parent = DS.Model.extend({
    ...
    grandParent: DS.belongsTo('Grandparent', { async: true }),

    child: DS.belongsTo('Child', { async: true })
});

App.Child = DS.Model.extend({
    ...
});
```

**Code Sample**

```
    var client = this.modelFor('workspace.client');


    var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve)
    {

        client.get('sessions').then(function(sessions)
        {

            Ember.RSVP.all(sessions.getEach('exercises')).then(function(exercises)
            {

                Ember.RSVP.all(exercises.getEach('exercise')).then(function()
                {

                    console.log("RESOLVED");

                    resolve(sessions);

                });


            });


        });

    });
```

Comment: can you add a sample of your `massive jumble` ?

Comment: Sample has been added. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simple get away by chaining the promises.

```
var client = this.modelFor('workspace.client');

return client.get('sessions').then(function(sessions) {
  return Ember.RSVP.all(sessions.getEach('exercises'));
}).then(function(exercises) {
  return Ember.RSVP.all(exercises.getEach('exercise'));
}).then(function(allExercises) {
  console.log("RESOLVED");
  return allExercises;
});
```

*note: not sure what you are trying to do when resolving with sessions, and not doing anything with the exercises*